# Increase CoAP receive package size beyond 579 bytes on SIM7080G modem

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, coap, sim7600

### Problem:

The SIM7080G modem is only able to receive a CoAP packet of maximum 579 bytes from a CoAP server (579 bytes total packet size, 566 bytes payload), even though the server sends a larger payload (800 bytes).

Example of AT command sequence:

```
AT+CCOAPINIT
AT+CCOAPURL="coap://coap.mydomain.com:5683"
AT+CCOAPPARA="CODE",1,uri-path,0,"myuri",token,0,"TCGHEHOSTXQAFGY"
AT+CCOAPACTION

Response: AT+CCOAPACTION
+CCOAPACTION: 0,0
OK
+CCOAPRECV: 0,579,566
```

Where 579 and 566 are the packet and payload sizes, respectively, in bytes.

### Expected response:

`+CCOAPRECV: 0,813,800`

The modem should be able to receive the entire payload (800 bytes) from the server, and support packet sizes up to a maximum of 1024 bytes as according to [RFC7252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252).

### Investigated documentation:

```
SIM7070_SIM7080_SIM7090 Series_AT Command Manual v1.07
SIM7070_SIM7080_SIM7090 Series_CoAP(S)_Application Note v1.03
```

The only thing i can find is this on page 17 of the AT command manual:

> The Command line buffer can accept a maximum of 559 characters (counted from the first command
> without "AT" or "at" prefix) or 39 AT commands. If the characters entered exceeded this number then none
> of the Command will executed and TA will return "ERROR".

However, this does not correspond with the numbers (579, 566) I'm seeing, although close.

### Question:

How can I make the SIM7080G Modem receive larger CoAP packets?
Is there a receive buffer i need to adjust to allow for larger packets?

Answer (score 0):

If the modem turns out to be unusable with larger packets, but does support sending custom CoAP options (if it does not support that, I recommend regarding it as broken and sending requests through UDP instead), you can address the issue at CoAP level by using block-wise requests and sending a Block2 request option described in [RFC7959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7959) indicating a request for only 512 bytes of payload.

Comment: RFC 8323 is CoAP over TCP..